# Making center a inline-block

Tags: html, css

I am having a hard time centering a inline block.

```
.content {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#main-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

#main-column {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#image {
    width: 150px !important;
    height: 150px !important;
}
```

*HTML*

```
@foreach($estates as $estate)
    <div id="main-wrapper">
         <div id="main-column">
               <div class="sub-column">
                    <img id="image" src="{{$estate->image}}">
               </div>
               <div class="sub-column">
                    Content
               </div>
               <div class="sub-column">
                    Buttons
               </div>
         </div>
     </div>
@endforeach
```

I don't want to make center element's inside sub-columns image and text etc. Just want to make a center main-column. This is the image of the page[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be certain without seeing the surrounding code, but try moving the `#main-wraper` and `#main-column` elements out of the `@foreach` loop.

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="main-column">
        @foreach($estates as $estate)
            <div class="sub-column">
                <img id="image" src="{{$estate->image}}">
            </div>
            <div class="sub-column">
                Content
            </div>
            <div class="sub-column">
                Buttons
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Be aware that an `id` attribute is supposed to be a unique value on the page. `#image` is currently not unique if there's more than one `$estate`. Consider using a `class` attribute on the `<img>` elements instead.

Answer (score 0):

Inline blocks works like if they were words of text, use `text-align: center` on the parent and it will center the line.

```
#main-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
```

I'm not really sure why are you using inline blocks, if you just want `#main-column` to be centered, use:

```
#main-column {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  // note there's no display: inline-block here
}
```

Comment: okay the problem is, when I do that the sub columns are not floating left to the right. I want those to be next to each other not below. That's why I use inline block.